# Nuget package content

Tags: nuget

I downloaded the Nuget package

> microsoft.aspnet.webapi.5.2.0.nupkg

but there are no dlls in there. How does this nuget package work ? Was excepting dlls in side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.0 does not contain any dlls itself it depends on the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost NuGet package which does contain dlls. The Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost also depends on other NuGet packages, and so on.

In the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.5.2.0.nupkg there is a .nuspec file which defines the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="[5.2.0, 5.3.0)" />
</dependencies>
```

If you install the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/) it will be easier to see how this works. The NuGet Package Explorer allows you to find, download and look inside NuGet packages without having to download and unzip them manually.